# Why does django-q throw exception with arrow time

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-q, python-arrow

I'm trying to create a Django-q schedule and following the documents to use `arrow` for the next run I get the following error with the schedule:

```py
schedule(
        func='test.tasks.test_task',
        name='test_task_nightly',
        schedule_type=Schedule.DAILY,
        next_run=arrow.utcnow().replace(hour=23, minute=30),
        q_options={'timeout': 10800, 'max_attempts': 1},
    )
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
    schedule(
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_q/tasks.py", line 122, in schedule
    s.full_clean()
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1209, in full_clean
    self.clean_fields(exclude=exclude)
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1251, in clean_fields
    setattr(self, f.attname, f.clean(raw_value, self))
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 650, in clean
    value = self.to_python(value)
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1318, in to_python
    parsed = parse_datetime(value)
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py", line 107, in parse_datetime
    match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Not sure why it's not accepting the time format similar to the example given in the django-q documentation page.

EDIT:
The task being scheduled:

```py
def test_task():
    print('Executed test task')
```

Nothing too complex just for testing purposes

Answer (score 2):

The Django ORM (verion 3.2 at time of writing) won't accept an Arrow object in any `DateTimeField`.

Arrow objects emulate Python's `datetime` object interface, but they are not real `datetime` objects. So any code receiving an Arrow object will fail if it explicitly checks if your value is an honest-to-goodness `datetime`. Which is exactly what the code in
`django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField.to_python` appears to be doing:

```py
def to_python(self, value):
    if value is None:
        return value
    if isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):
        return value
    if isinstance(value, datetime.date):
        value = datetime.datetime(value.year, value.month, value.day)
    ...
    try:
        parsed = parse_datetime(value)
```

As you can see, when it doesn't match a `datetime` or `date` instance, Django hands it off to the `parse_datetime()` function to deal with, which expects a string. Which explains your error: `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

You can get around this by getting the `.datetime` property, which will return a plain old python `datetime`, i.e.

```py
schedule(
        func='test.tasks.test_task',
        name='test_task_nightly',
        schedule_type=Schedule.DAILY,
        next_run=arrow.utcnow().replace(hour=23, minute=30).datetime,
        q_options={'timeout': 10800, 'max_attempts': 1},
    )
```